# Including especial characters in android preferences.xml

Tags: android, xml, preferences

I want to include an item in my `preferences.xml` file that it contains a `special character @`.

```
           <EditTextPreference
            android:title="@string/pref_char_pares_title"
            android:summary="@string/pref_char_pares_summary"
            android:key="charseppares"
            android:defaultValue="@"/>
```

But I have an error in line `android:defaultValue="@"`

(error: Error: No resource type specified (at 'defaultValue' with value '@').

I want to use the character @ like separator character in my strings. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
  <EditTextPreference
            android:title="@string/pref_char_pares_title"
            android:summary="@string/pref_char_pares_summary"
            android:key="charseppares"
            android:defaultValue="\@"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

//you can also use like this to show special char

```
Unicode number: U+0040
HTML-code: &#64;
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but I had the same problem and maybe it will be helpful for somebody.

```
<EditTextPreference
android:title="@string/pref_char_pares_title"
android:summary="@string/pref_char_pares_summary"
android:key="charseppares"
android:defaultValue="\u0040"/>
```